# qsub array job delay

Tags: linux, bash, hpc, pbs, qsub

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -N garunsmodel
#PBS -l mem=2g
#PBS -l walltime=1:00:00
#PBS -t 1-2
#PBS -e error/error.txt
#PBS -o error/output.txt
#PBS -A improveherds_my
#PBS -m ae

set -x
c=$PBS_ARRAYID

nodeDir=`mktemp -d /tmp/phuong.XXXXX`
cp -r /group/dairy/phuongho/garuns $nodeDir
cp /group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/my/simplex.bin $nodeDir/garuns/simplex.bin
cp /group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/nttp.txt $nodeDir/garuns/my.txt
cp /group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/delay_input.txt $nodeDir/garuns/delay_input.txt

cd $nodeDir/garuns

module load gcc vle

XXX=`pwd`

sed -i "s|/group/dairy/phuongho/garuns/out|$XXX/out/|" exp/garuns.vpz

awk -v i="$c" 'NR == 1 || $8==i' my.txt > simplex-observed.txt
awk -v i="$c" 'NR == 1 || $7==i {print $6}' delay_input.txt > afm_param.txt
cp "/group/dairy/phuongho/garuns_param.txt" "$nodeDir/garuns/garuns_param.txt"
while true
do
./simplex.bin &
sleep 5m
done

awk 'NR >1' < simplex-optimum-output.csv>> /group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/my/finalresuls${c}.csv
cp simplex-all-output.csv "/group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/my/simplex-all-output${c}.csv"
#awk '$28==1{print $1, $12,$26,$28,c}' c=$c out/exp_tempfile.csv > /group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/my/simulated_my${c}.csv
cp /out/exp_tempfile.csv /group/dairy/phuongho/jo/parity1/my/exp_tempfile${c}.csv

rm simplex-observed.txt
rm garuns_param.txt
```

I have above bash script that allows submitting multiple jobs at the same time via PBS_ARRAYID. My issue is that my model (simplex.bin) when it executes it writes something to my home directory. Thus, if one jobs runs at a time or wait until next jobs finished writing stuff to home then it is fine. However, as I want to have >1000 jobs running at a time, 1000 of them try to write the same stuff to home, then leading to crash.
Is there any a smart way to just submit the second job after the first one has already started for a certain amount of time (let's say 5 minutes)?
I already checked and found two options: starts 2nd job when 1st finished, or start at a specific date/time.

Thanks

Comment: You can also star the first job in the background, sleep for some time, start the second job in the background and go on further that way

Comment: @GMichael: can you make it  more clearly please?

Comment: Please see my answer below

Comment: Modifying the program to write to a unique output file would be the most efficient solution.

Comment: @tripleee: the command within 'simplex.bin. that always writes stuff to home directory is from the VLE (www.vle-project.org/) which I do not fully understand. I am contacting my French colleague to solve this but in the mean time, I think it might be good if I can find an alternative solution.

Comment: What does `simplex.bin` do? Creating a basically infinite number of instances in each job can hardly be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following:

```
while [ yes ]
do
     ./simplex.bin &
     sleep 2
done
```

It endlessly starts `./simplex.bin` process in the background, waits for 2 seconds, starts a new `./simplex.bin`, etc.

Please note that you may also need `nohup` and add standard input/output redirection for your `./simplex.bin`. Depending on your exact requirements

Comment: You probably want `while true;` as `yes` never finishes (and fills your stdout with text) and using `[` in this context is rather superfluous.

Comment: I am currently testing your suggestions! Thanks

Comment: I'd actually suggest `while sleep 2` -- that way if you send the sleep a SIGTERM the loop won't continue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Torque, you can set a limit on the number of jobs that can run concurrently:

```
# Only allow 100 jobs to concurrently execute from this job array
qsub myscript.sh -t 0-10000%100
```

I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but I'm guessing you can find a slot limit that'll make it run without crashing.